# What Regex would capture everything from second : mark to the end of a line?

Tags: regex

Target:

```
: (x.S.) xxxx xxxx (xxx  xx xx xxxx): Expected xxxxxxx 2021
```

My regex:

```
\:.*\r
```

Adding `^\r` or changing `\r` to `\n` don't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you can say that your strings always contain two colon's I think I'd go with something along the lines of:

```
\b[^:\r\n]+$
```

- `b` - Word boundary
- `[^:\r\n]+)` - Negated colon, carriage return or newline (one or more)
- `$` - End string ancor

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D4WcJv/5)

---

If you want to explicitly test for two colon's in your string and return everything after the second one (including possible colons), you might want to use:

```
^(?:[^:]*:){2}\s*(.*)$
```

- `^` - Start string ancor
- `(?:`- Non-capturing group

  - `[^:]*):` - Negated colon zero or more times followed by colon
  - `{2}` - Repeat non-capturing group two times
- `\s*` - Zero or more spaces
- `(.*)` - Capturing group holding anything but newlines
- `$` - End string ancor

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D4WcJv/3)

---

Though, as most languages do also have some sort of `Split()` function, you could decide on researching that and ditch regular expressions.

Comment: As as a mere suggestion, in the first pattern all the quantifiers are optional and could also match an empty line and the pattern will try to explore a match from every position. Depending on what is supported of course,  you could mark the start of the match with a word boundary `\b[^:\r\n]+$` or a whitespace boundary on the left using `(?<!\S)[^:\r\n]+$`   for example. +1

Comment: Thank for the constructive feedback @TheFourthBird. I'll see to it a little later.

Comment: just also realized that MSwords has a wildcard function and adobe acrobat will format w/ certain styles so you can edit certain parts of the documents all at once